# How to click on an input type submit with no defined ID using selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium

I'm testing selenium to manipulate the browser to access my account on my website. But it turns out that the site I bought does not have login buttons with id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try with the other attribute's which are available in the `input` tag like
`name` `value` and `type`

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//frame[@name='mainFrame']"))     

user_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type = 'text' and @name='codigo']")

user_input.send_keys(USERNAME)

password_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type = 'password' and @name='clave']")

password_input.send_keys(PASSWORD)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type = 'submit' and @value='Ingresar']")

login_button.click()
```

And you can click on the Reset button if you want

```
 reset_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type = 'reset' and @value='Limpiar']")
 
 reset_button.click()
```

**code**

```
from selenium import webdriver

USERNAME = "admin"
PASSWORD = "admin"

driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//frame[@name='mainFrame']"))

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Dev\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://localhost:8080/')

user_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type = 'text' and @name='codigo']")
user_input.send_keys(USERNAME)

password_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type = 'password' and @name='clave']")
password_input.send_keys(PASSWORD)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type = 'submit' and @value='Ingresar']")
login_button.click()
```

**import**

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Comment: Too I get this: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type = 'submit' and @value='Ingresar']"}`

Comment: Can you share the URL

Comment: Is localhost :P

Comment: okay can you check if it is not in the Iframe

Comment: can you show the more relevant HTML source related to the login

Comment: This is the login page: https://pastebin.com/FWrijhb3

Comment: Okay is it the same page which you working on?

Comment: Yes, it is the same, but I have not published online it because I am doing tests to login automatically.

Comment: Okay sure I'm checking it

Comment: So you are not able to get the submit button and rest all the fields are working properly I mean the XPath?

Comment: can you check I've updated my answer can you try and let me know if it works

Comment: I get this: `   login_button = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[@type = 'submit' and @value='Ingresar']')))
                                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?`

Comment: can you pls check now ?

Comment: Get this:  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: can you check now  the updated answer I think instead of value I should only use type in the XPath

Comment: I have a question, how can I implement `login_form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='gupprincipal.valida_inicio']")` to be able to validate the username and password?

Comment: @Spvda I think you raise another question if you check this answer this also working as in the other question you provided the link so based on that I have updated the code here you can check it here let me know if it is working, earlier I told you to check if there is frame the Exception is displayed because of frame

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong locators.
F.e. the username input field. As you can see it is a `name` attribute there with unique value `codigo`, it's not an `id` attribute.
Similarly with the other elements.
So, your code with the correct locators may look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
 
USERNAME = admin
PASSWORD = admin

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Dev\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://localhost:8080/')



user_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="codigo"]')
user_input.send_keys(USERNAME)


password_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="clave"]')
password_input.send_keys(PASSWORD)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="submit"]')
login_button.click()
```

You can use XPath instead CSS selectors as well.
Also, you have to add waits, preferably the explicit wait, in order to access the elements only when they are loaded.
With it your code will look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 
USERNAME = admin
PASSWORD = admin

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Dev\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('http://localhost:8080/')


wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="codigo"]'))).send_keys(USERNAME)


driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="clave"]').send_keys(PASSWORD)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="submit"]'))).click()
```

Comment: I get this: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type = 'submit' and @value='Ingresar']"}`

Comment: I used `input[type="submit"]` css_selector locator, not `//input[@type = 'submit' and @value='Ingresar']`!